# SEHException was unhandeled

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using Windows 7 x64, EmguCV 2.4.9. When I run the code in my laptop it is showing this problem below. In my Desktop the code is working well. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem:

The Code is Given Below:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

        if (currentFrame != null)
        {
            Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            **var detectedFaces = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(haarCascade)[0];  ///Problem arises in this line::: SEHException was unhandeled**

            foreach (var face in detectedFaces)
                currentFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(0, double.MaxValue, 0), 3);

            image1.Source = ToBitmapSource(currentFrame);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

            BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                ptr,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
            return bs;
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        capture = new Capture();
        haarCascade = new HaarCascade(@"C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\opencv\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

}

I have copied the opencv_xxx.dll in my bin\debug and system32. But still getting the problem. Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post details of the exception? It could be any one of a number of things, and the exception will help to narrow it down.

Comment: I think I am seeing the same issue. Did you get to the bottom of this?